# Where do we post REST and Web services Questions?

Tags: support, scope

These are mostly technology agnostic, but up till now they have been on stackoverflow. Should we start using stackapps for this ? Or will there be any "looselycoupler.com" where we could discuss all software and integration design/architecture...etc :) Would be great for architects

Comment: If they are on SO, please tag with [web-development], then I won't have to see then :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Apps is the place for applications that use the Stack Overflow API, it is not a general application Q&A. So unless those questions have to do with said API, they definitely don't fit on Stack Apps.

As far as I know, they're still valid questions on Stack Overflow and they don't have any problems staying there. You might check [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) to see if there are any site proposals that will contain these questions, but even if one is established it won't necessarily drag that subject away from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You should only ask questions that are specifically about the Stack Exchange API on StackApps (see the [FAQ](https://stackapps.com/faq)).  Questions about REST and Web services in general should go on Stack Overflow (as long as they also relate to *programming* with REST and Web services).